# Signing and Submitting Firefox WebExtension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am able to port my chrome extension(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipmystuff/ponkmhjofooonokejbbmladaomkbbgcd) to Firefox EebExtension, everything is working fine in Firefox(46), but I am unable to publish the extension to Mozilla store. After uploading my extension on add-on developer hub, it got stuck at step 2.

step2: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/submit/2

It is stuck at step 2 from past 4 hours, is there some else that I have to do for WebExtension.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cancel/go back and try to upload again.

With non-WebExtension add-ons, I have had it hang more than once at that point of the process. The first time it hung, I let it sit for quite a while prior to canceling and trying again (even if that means clicking *back* or killing the tab). Now, if it looks like it is hanging, I just try again relatively rapidly.

The validation step is an automated check of your extension. That step should take moments, *at most* minutes for large/complex extensions. After the first success, you will have a feel for how long it should take for your extension. If it takes significantly longer than that time, just go back and try uploading again.